# How to hide ipywidget code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, hide, ipywidgets

I am writting a jupyter notebook in which at the begining I am creating a complex `tab` `ipywidget` for the user to select some inptus (see picture). I am wondering if there is any way to *hide* to the user the code cell that contains the code to create that widget.

I saw on this forum some questiosn about hiding code when exporting the notebook but in my case the user will access the j_notebook online. Just would like to avoid complexity by hiding some code cells

[image]

Comment: Once you have developed your code, can you place it in a .py file and then import your widgets from that module into your notebook? That would leave you with just one line of code at the least...

Comment: @ac24 Good suggestion. Would this be the code to use? `%run /my/path/widgets.py`?

Comment: if it's in the same directory as the nb, just 'import widgets'. If a level down, say in a folder called 'helpers', add an empty file named __init__.py to the folder, then from your notebook  use form helpers import widgets.  PS be careful naming your import 'widgets'. It feels like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

in module.py

```py
import ipywidgets as ipyw
from IPython.display import display
button = ipyw.Button('Try this:')
out = ipyw.Output()

def print_it(button):
    with out:
        print('You clicked it')

button.on_click(print_it)

display(ipyw.VBox(children=[button, out]))
```

In your notebook:

```
import module
```